# FATAL EXCEPTION: FirebaseMLHandler

Tags: android-studio, dependencies, firebase-mlkit

When i run my android app, logcat showing following this error:
FATAL EXCEPTION: FirebaseMLHandler
Process: fr.myluckyday.myverimed, PID: 15453
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field zzbis of type I in class Lcom/google/firebase/ml/vision/barcode/internal/BarcodeDetectorOptionsParcel; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.ml.vision.barcode.internal.BarcodeDetectorOptionsParcel' appears in /data/app/~~_BRWdWVND46UrTRPIi-iYg==/fr.myluckyday.myverimed-BB5LdJZh5-UCx0k9n3ASNw==/base.apk)
at com.google.firebase.ml.vision.barcode.zzb.(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model@@16.0.1:3)
at com.google.firebase.ml.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetectorCreator.newBarcodeDetector(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model@@16.0.1:2)
at com.google.firebase.ml.vision.barcode.internal.zza.zzps(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision@@24.0.1:29)
at com.google.firebase.ml.vision.barcode.internal.zza.zznu(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision@@24.0.1:10)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzpz.zzf(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common@@22.0.1:53)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzpz$zza.zznx(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common@@22.0.1:7)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzpz$zza.call(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common@@22.0.1:24)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzpf.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common@@22.0.1:32)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzpe.run(Unknown Source:4)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zze.dispatchMessage(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common@@22.0.1:6)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
2023-09-13 14:59:46.179 15525-15620 AndroidRuntime          pid-15525                            E  FATAL EXCEPTION: FirebaseMLHandler
Process: fr.myluckyday.myverimed, PID: 15525
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field zzbis of type I in class Lcom/google/firebase/ml/vision/barcode/internal/BarcodeDetectorOptionsParcel; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.ml.vision.barcode.internal.BarcodeDetectorOptionsParcel' appears in /data/app/~~_BRWdWVND46UrTRPIi-iYg==/fr.myluckyday.myverimed-BB5LdJZh5-UCx0k9n3ASNw==/base.apk)
at com.google.firebase.ml.vision.barcode.zzb.(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model@@16.0.1:3)
at com.google.firebase.ml.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetectorCreator.newBarcodeDetector(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model@@16.0.1:2)
at com.google.firebase.ml.vision.barcode.internal.zza.zzps(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision@@24.0.1:29)
at com.google.firebase.ml.vision.barcode.internal.zza.zznu(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision@@24.0.1:10)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzpz.zzf(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common@@22.0.1:53)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzpz$zza.zznx(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common@@22.0.1:7)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzpz$zza.call(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common@@22.0.1:24)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzpf.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common@@22.0.1:32)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzpe.run(Unknown Source:4)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zze.dispatchMessage(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common@@22.0.1:6)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)

I am tring to solve this bugs for some days. But i couldn't identify and solve.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

ML Kit became a standalone SDK outside firebase since 2020. Could you see if migrating to the new API works for you? https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/migration